# Bookmarkable Ajax

Tags: html, ajax

I'm paginating a list of items, and currently the page listed on page load is set by a GET variable (e.g. www.example.com/page.html?page=2). I want to switch it to ajax, but I'm worried users won't be able to bookmark the page they want to view.

Is there a way I can update the URL without redirecting the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with a hash in the url. You can learn more [here](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs).

You can also find a nice jquery plugin for that purpose [here](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).

Regards

Answer (score 4):

**Use hash**

Your website is www.example.com/page.html

**Part I.**

When you load page two using ajax add a hash to the url 
www.example.com/page.html#page2
You can do that using javascript 
window.location.hash = "page2".
Now users can bookmark www.example.com/page.html#page2

**part II.**

When a user request a page say, www.example.com/page.html#page2
You can read the hash using javascript.

var myHash = window.location.hash
If myHash is empty load the page normally.
If it contains "page2", then load the content of page2.